# Displaying a result after receiving user input

Tags: android, sdk, textview, output

I'm developing an app in `Android` and need to implement a common app function- accepting numeric input from the user via a `EditText`. After typing in this value, I want the user to be able to be select a 'go' `button`. A result should then appear below the first `TextView`. What should I use to display the result (TextView etc?) and how can I go about implementing this process. Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is covered in the very first Android Developer SDK tutorial for when you download Eclipse.

Comment: You need to use EditText to allow the user to input values like a String. You can then create a button with a click listener that shows the EditText value in a TextView. This is pretty basic, start learning EditText, then Button, then TextView and then put them all together.

Answer (score 1):

You are new to this so First check d link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_event_handling.htm  .

Here You have to define 1 `TextView` , 1 `EditText` and 1 `Button`

like

```
 Button _go = (Button) findViewById(R.id._btngo);
```

than

```
_go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
      TextView _getdata= (TextView) findViewById(R.id._tvresult);
      EditText _result= (EditText) findViewById(R.id._etgetinput);
          // get the input value and store as a string
            String result = _result.getText().toString(); 
           // display the result in textview

               getdata.setText(result); 

           }
        });
```

Hope you will find the solution .. :)